# How to play video using embed code(not in youtube embed code another link video embed code)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, embed

This is my embed code. I have use this code and need to run the video on iPhones:

```
<object id="flashObj" 
  width="400" height="265" 
  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" 
  codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
  <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
  <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=1572434110001&playerID=1456553457001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABNxei5wk~,PMun_jKGs7kvG5zhX_FbSH9tFMK-pdC1&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
  <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
  <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" 
    bgcolor="#FFFFFF" 
    flashVars="videoId=1572434110001&playerID=1456553457001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABNxei5wk~,PMun_jKGs7kvG5zhX_FbSH9tFMK-pdC1&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true"
  base="http://admin.brightcove.com" 
    name="flashObj" 
    width="400" 
    height="265"
    seamlesstabbing="false" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    allowFullScreen="true" 
    allowScriptAccess="always" 
    swLiveConnect="true" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flash objects are not supported on iOS devices. So this code won't work. If it is a youtube video, you'll either need to use the YouTube embed code (i.e. webview opening the URL) or open the video detail page in YouTube on a browser.

There is no other direct way to show YouTube videos inside an iOS app using the iOS SDK.

Comment: if any possible is there to convert this flash embed code into non flash embed code and finally run in iPhone apps???

Comment: You might want to try these - https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser, https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView (not sure if they work - I haven't used them)